# Custom UIView gets attched to MainViewcontoller

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, uiview, uiviewcontroller

[image]I created a customView that I used as a tooltip in my Map application. The custom view is created by using xib and it shows up but the problem I have now is instead of the view to remain as it was created, it goes on to attach itself to the top of the view controller.

below is the xib file and what I want my view to look like

[image]

here is what shows up on my device when I run it in simulator

[image]

how can Make this view the size I want it to be and not attach to the to of the ViewController.

I called the InfoView like

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoContents marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
    guard let placeMarker = marker as? PlaceMarker else {
      return nil
    }
    guard let infoView = UIView.viewFromNibName("MarkerInfoView") as? MarkerInfoView else {
      return nil
    }

    infoView.nameLabel.text = placeMarker.place.name
    if let photo = placeMarker.place.photo {
      infoView.placePhoto.image = photo
    } else {
      infoView.placePhoto.image = UIImage(named: "generic")
    }

    return infoView
  }
```

Comment: Did you set up any constraints in the xib?

Comment: yes I did, All UI component were constrained

Comment: Where DO you want the view to appear instead?

Comment: on the map when I select a marker

Comment: Got that. But where exactly?

Comment: I want it to appear on the map just like a toolTip

Comment: Show us a screenshot of the XIB with all the constraints

Comment: @hardikparmar that is the first image in the question

Comment: @hardikparmar I have updated it with the Image

Comment: it isn't attaching to main vc, looks like its height is too much!

Comment: Yes. The hight is too much, plus can I make the corners of the toolTip rounded or make the background color clear? Because I’m getting a square tooltip after making the edges round

Comment: @vacawama yes but I would undo the delete now so anyone with similar issue can get an answer